# How to disable the escape characters in mysql output text file?

Tags: mysql

I used the following command to export a table into a text file:

`select * into outfile '/test/output4.txt' fields terminated by '||' enclosed by '"' from area`

When any field in the table contains the characters '\n', the output file will start a new line as '\n' is an escape character. But I need to display the original character '\n' instead of translate it and start a new line in the output file. Is there any way to solve this?

For example, create a table and insert a record as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test1`(`id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, `title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, `author` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ));  
insert into test1 (title,author) values ("000","a\nbc");
```

Then using the command:

```
select * into outfile '/test/output4.txt' fields terminated by '||' enclosed by '"' from test1
```

The output file is like:

```
"1"||"000"||"a\  
bc"
```

But the preferred output is:

```
"1"||"000"||"a\nbc"
```

Comment: Provide source data sample as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (2-3 records).

Comment: *`insert into test1 (title,author) values ("000","a\nbc");`* inserts linebreak! If you want to insert 2-char literal `'\n'` then you must use `insert into test1 (title,author) values ("000","a\\nbc");`

Comment: @Akina No I can't change the data in the database but I have to display all stored '\n' as the character '\n' rather than displaying a new line.  I know this requirement is strange. By the way, if I use the command ```mysql -P 3307 --protocol=tcp -h  xxx xxx -e "select * from test1" >test1.txt``` then in test1.txt it can display '\n' and not start a new line but in this way I can't set the delimiter between fields.

Comment: Process the column value in SELECT (instead of asterisk) accordingly. Like in https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ce13b37be5d720f32bfe78dce3ad54d2

Comment: @Akina I tried ```select title,replace(author,'\n','\\n') from test1``` but it didn't work. Then I tried ```select title,replace(author,'\n','\\\n') from test1``` and it worked perfectly. However when I used ```select title,replace(author,'\n','\\n') into outfile '/test/output4.txt' fields terminated by '||' from test1``` it still broke the line. I also tried ```select title,replace(author,'\n','\\\n') into outfile '/test/output4.txt' fields terminated by '||'  from test1``` but the '\n' is replaced by '\\n', not '\n'. I don't understand and it's strange.